# CBN_SELCHANGE in Dynamically created ComboBoxes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

How to get the CBN_SELCHANGE in dynamically created CComboBoxes??.. I used a array of CComboBoxes.

```
MyCComboBox * p_ComboBoxes = new MyCComboBox[numberOcComboBoxes]; //numberOcComboBoxes determined at rumtime
```

In the message Map of MyCComboBox

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyCComboBox , CComboBox)
    ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(CBN_SELCHANGE, &CTestDlg::OnCbnSelchange)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CTestDlg::OnCbnSelchange()
{
this->GetDlgCtrlID(); // Get The ComboBox ID;
CString sText;
p_ComboBoxes[0].GetLBText(p_ComboBoxes[0].GetCurSel() , sText); // I can't access like this 


}
```

// Initialization of the p_ComboBoxes Array..

```
for (int i = 0 ;i < iNumber ; i++)
{


p_ComboBoxes[i].Create(WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|CBS_DROPDOWN,
        CRect(10 + MY_PIC_ADDITIONAL_WIDTH,iItemDrawHeight,10 + MY_PIC_ADDITIONAL_WIDTH +MY_PIC_PROPERTY_WIDTH
        ,iItemDrawHeight +MY_PIC_HEIGHT), this, pImageControlPropertyID[i]);

iItemDrawHeight += MY_PIC_PROPERTY_ADDITIONAL_HEIGHT;

}
```

I can't access the selected text it gives me "Access violation reading location 0x00000020" error..

Comment: are you sure `GetCurSel` doesn't return `CB_ERR`?

Comment: No problem is that I can't access CComboBox array.

Comment: When do you initialize `p_ComboBoxes`?

Comment: Inside the OnInitDialog() method.

Comment: Don't you need a two-step construction for combo boxes? So, you also need to call Create() on each combo box in your array.

Comment: *How* do you initialize the elements of `p_ComboBoxes`?  Code, please.

Comment: @Zeus, initialize it in the constructor

Comment: @aleguna: No, it probably should be in a `WM_INITDIALOG` handler if he wants the dialog to be the parent window to the ComboBox controls.

Comment: @jamesdlin I've added the initialization part also..

Comment: Wait a minute, `MyCComboBox`'s message map is trying to invoke a pointer-to-member-function from `CTestDlg`?  How do you expect that to work?

Comment: @jamesdlin When I run the program it will execute the OnCbnSelchange method. Which means MyCComboBox class has invoked the method. Is it not a good way to do this??...

Comment: @Zeus: If your message map is in `MyCComboBox`, then it it can't invoke methods in `CTestDlg` via a pointer-to-member-function.  How does it know *what object* to invoke the method on?

Comment: @jamesdlin But the interesting thing is When I select an item from any dynamically created combobox, The OnCbnSelchange method is called.

Comment: @Zeus: But when `OnCbnSelchange` is called, what is `this` pointing to?  A `CTestDlg` instance? A `MyCComboBox` instance? Garbage?

Comment: @jamesdlin CTestDlg Instance. I can get the this->GetDlgCtrlID(); It will get the exact ID of the MyCComboBox.

Comment: @Zeus: Huh?  Why would calling `GetDlgCtrlID` on a `CTestDlg` (which presumably a dialog that *contains* the various ComboBox controls) instance give you the ID of a `MyCComboBox`?  None of what you're saying makes much sense, so please just post a SSCCE instead of disconnected snippets.

Comment: @jamesdlin Can you please suggest me a way to identify which MyCComboBox has trigged in the  OnCbnSelchange method??..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, ON_CONTROL_REFLECT is for handling the message *in the control class*, not in the parent dialog class. You should be implementing your OnCbnSelchange() handler in the MyCComboBox class and adding an ON_CONTROL_REFLECT entry in the MyCComboBox message map.

If you really want to handle the message in the parent dialog, you should use the ON_CONTROL macro - one entry for each child combo each with a separate handler so you can tell which one sent the message.

Comment: The problem is that I can't exactly tell how many combo boxes will be created before the rumtime.

Comment: That's only a problem if you try to handle the message in the parent dialog class. If you handle it in the control class, it doesn't matter how many instances of the combo you create.

Answer (score 1):

You could also override `OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`
in the parent dialog window. If `HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELCHANGE`, then compare
`LOWORD(wParam)` against the id's of your controls.

```
BOOL CMyDlg::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELCHANGE) { //A combo box selection changed
        int ID = LOWORD(wParam); //The ID of the corresponding ComboBox
        //Perform additional handling...
    }
    return CDialog::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
}
```